# Bunny lays down (like a pancake) when I pat him

Tags: behavior, health, rabbits, play

My Bunny was neglected and only on pellets for about 5 years (before I got him). When I pat him he often lays down (legs underneath him), is that good? Also, how do I get him happier? He is free roamed, gets vegetables, lots of love but doesn't play with any toys.

Comment: if he is 5 years old, he is a senior and not this playful like young rabbits. you could give him some tasks to earn his food. I ve got a 3 year old rabbit that lived before in a little cage and she needed almost one year to get enough muscles to find fun in playing (running, climbing, jumping)

Comment: @Allerleirauh I would not say 5 years is an absolute senior, it depends on the rabbit and the breed.  At 5 many rabbits still have 8 or 10 years to live.  There is a good summary here https://rabbit.org/signs-of-aging/

Comment: @JamesJenkins okay, I used the false word. I like to say that with 5 years the rabbit is not a junior any more and less playfull. The senior status is lesser playful and less moving in general then :)

Answer (score 3):

Bunnies laying down to pancake are a great sign, it means they are comfortable.

Rabbits do need enrichment items (toys), but not all rabbits like the same toys. My former rabbit loved fling toys--things like baby toy keys that he could throw with his mouth. My current rabbit doesn't really like those; she prefers chew toys such as willow balls and loves running around her tunnel.

[Here is a great resource](https://www.angelfire.com/fl/RabbitRescue/shybunny.html) on how to win over a shy rabbit if that is something you are still concerned about.

Comment: Hi Rosie, the link you provided is to unsecure website, and I found very similar article from same author [here](https://www.angelfire.com/fl/RabbitRescue/shybunny.html) which is secure and also has a design. Which is more correct and/or up-to-date? If the later, can you please change the link in the answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: Done. Thank you for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Bunny lays down (like a pancake) when I pat him

I am not sure what you mean by 'pat', if you mean the verb 'touch quickly and gently with the flat of the hand' then you are doing it wrong.

Bunnies like to be stroked. Soft pets that glide easily over the fur.  I go into some [detail in this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/13812/13).

As for playing with toys:

Cats and dogs like to chase things (think catch and eat prey).

Rabbits don't chase things, they will occasionally toss things.  But they play different than cats and dogs.  They like things to chew on and dig in.

- [digging box](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1821/13)